# getting directory of a specific file in a folder and save it into a variable

Tags: command-line

Here is my problem. I want to store the directory of a specific file in a variable via terminal but in my folder there are many files let say one of them is test1432.config and the other is test1432-busybox.config and the other files whose extention are not .config. So I decided to write

```
fst_directory="%s" %(co_directory[3:])+ "/*.config"
```

But If I do that in this way, it also takes the test1432-busybox.config doesnt it ? How could I do that ? thanks in advance

**EDIT**

The only differences between two file is the busybox part. I mean fileName-busybox.config and fileName.config. I always want to choose fileName.config

**EDIT2**

Since nobody share the solution. I created my own. In this case the busybox is not necessary file for me . So I decided to delete them and after that I can choose the true file easly. If the file is important and you could not delete it.You can move it somewhere else and move back after the operation.

Comment: My problem was that. There are more than one file with .config extantion and I just want to get one of them. So I do it by this way.
fst_directory="%s/%s"%(co_directory[3:],fst_firmware_name)+"/*%s.config"%(fst_firmware_name)     
In this way, it takes only the "blablbla"fst_firmware_name.config file
I hope I Could help @Braiam

Comment: Sorry for being vague, share your solution in the answers below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have two files, one you want to list/use and one you want to ignore with the one to ignore containing `-` in it's filename as in -busybox:

```
 ls *.config | grep -v '-'
```

From man page about grep -v option:

```
      -v, --invert-match
          Invert  the  sense  of matching, to select non-matching lines.  (-v is specified by
          POSIX.)
```

Which basically means list all files ending with `.config`, pipe to grep and exclude those containing `-`

Or something that gives more control over the selection:

```
 ls | grep ".*[^-busybox].config"
```

Which means:

List all files in directory pipe them to grep and using a regular expression filter them to include `*` for everything but not those in brackets `[^-busybox]`, ending with `.config`

`[^]` excludes.